# Akka Client actor connecting to Server actor system

Tags: java, akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

I have server actor running in the background. The basic operation of the server actor is to get a key and a value pair. Once it receives the pair, it stores it in a map and returns it when asked.
Now, I have a client actor. I want to the connect to the server actor using actorSelection() method. But I am confused with the parameters it takes. Can anyone help me understand what parameters it takes ?

Server side:-
Actor System: actorSystem
Server Actor: akkademy-db

Client side:-
Actor System: LocalSystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention that your scenario is from the book *Learning Akka*. As stated in the book, the client can obtain an `ActorSelection` of the server with the following:

```
ActorSelection remoteDb = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://akkademy@" + remoteAddress + "/user/akkademy-db")
```

The template for the path, as the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/remoting.html#looking-up-remote-actors) describes, is the following:

```
akka.<protocol>://<actor system name>@<hostname>:<port>/<actor path>
```

Using the template, here's a breakdown of the `ActorSelection` path to the server:

```
"akka.tcp://akkademy@" + remoteAddress + "/user/akkademy-db"
//   tcp               --> protocol
//   akkademy          --> actor system name
//   remoteAddress     --> hostname:port
//   /user/akkademy-db --> actor path
```

Read the documentation for more information.